# Get_term_meta() does not work with pre_get_posts()

Tags: categories, actions, meta-query

I am trying to get custom term meta value for a certain category using get_term_meta() function. This value is stored in the wp_termmeta table. Then, based on that value, I want to modify the main query for a certain category archive page (sort the posts by date ascending). However, the pre_get_posts() hook that I am using does not allow me to do so. I tried all the ways that i am aware of, however, it is still not working

Here is my code:

```
function my_new_category_order( $query ) {
    //get the category id
    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
    //get the custom meta value
    $post_order = get_term_meta($cat_id, 'post-order', true);
    //The value is shown two times. First, it is false, then it is "oldest"
    var_dump($post_order); 

    //Cannot go inside the if statement because $post_order is false!
    if ( $post_order && $query->is_category($cat_id) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        //$post_order is false here
        var_dump($post_order);
        //$cat_id is empty string
        var_dump($cat_id);
    }


}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_new_category_order' );
```

As a result, I am not able to go inside the if statement and reorder the posts.. The rest of the code is working fine but the term meta value remains undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see, $query is undefined and returns null when accessed. 'edit_category' means a category has been edited, a save operation. You are not querying anything.
Altering sort order happens in 'pre_get_posts'. I don't understand what you are trying to do, or may be just trying to do two separate things in one action. Maybe split the two concerns.

Comment: I edited my question and uploaded the modified code. I am now using the pre_get_posts hook. However, it is still not working. I believe it is so, because the query runs before I am able to fetch data from wp_termmeta table.. how can i make it work? Please check my modified question.

Comment: I don't believe $post_order can change within the scope of a function without being set. Dump $cat_id and is_category and is_main_query too. Also set he query order without a condition to test it.

Comment: Should not be a problem to get meta, any time, anywhere. 'post-order' is correct key, not 'post_order'? - have to ask...

Comment: Yes, the key is post-order. Might be due to the fact that pre_get_posts gets the data before the actual query?

Comment: Nope. `get_{somekindof}_meta` functions and friends always work. Any function, or else a db-error or fatal error. What is the exact dump of `$cat_id`?

Comment: If i put var_dump($cat_id); inside the if, it gives an empty string (string(0) ""). If i put var_dump($cat_id); above the if statement, it gives string(0) "" on the very top of the page and it also prints int(7) on the page menu items.

Comment: It looks like $cat_id was also empty string.. Sorry, it was late at night and I was tired. The values for the meta value and the category are false and empty string. I edited my question again.

Comment: Maybe I should try to get the meta value with $wpdb?

Answer (score 0):

I finally, finally figured it out! I was not able to get the category id in the first place. Strangely, get_query_var('cat') is not working. Here is the way that worked for me, in case someone else also struggles with this:

```
function my_new_category_order( $query ) {
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $cat_id = $category->term_id;
    $post_order = get_term_meta($cat_id, 'post-order', true);
    //Now everything works!
    if ( $post_order =='oldest' && $query->is_category($cat_id) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_new_category_order' );
```